# ngRepeat does not remove old entries when directive manually replaces the element's content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive which uses different templates based on the some state of the `scope` like following one:

```
app.directive('foo', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      bar: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var tpl = scope.bar == 'foo' ? '<li><strong>{{bar}}</strong</li>' : '<li>{{bar}}</li>'
      element.replaceWith($compile(element.html(tpl).contents())(scope))
    }
  }
});
```

If I use this directive inside the `ngRepeat` loop and the array used has changed the new elements for the rendered but the old ones does not disappear.

```
<ul>
  <foo bar="bar" ng-repeat="bar in bars"></foo>
</ul>
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UnsrjPh8kW27bK8RbPgY

Can anyone point me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please note, that the `{{bar}}` inside of `<foo bar="bar" ng-repeat="bar in bars">{{bar}}</foo>` is useless (and should probably be removed) as long as your directive has not `transclude` set to true (i.e. it will simply be replaced).

Comment: you're right. that might be misleading. edited.

Answer (score 1):

This is because ng-repeat and directive creates their own scope..
Try using directive inside the ng-repeat...Its working for me..

html...

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p><button ng-click="changeBars()">Change bars</button></p>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="bar in bars"><foo bar="bar">{{bar}}</foo></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

and directive..

```
app.directive('foo', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      bar: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var tpl = scope.bar == 'foo' ? '<p><strong>{{bar}}</strong</p>' : '<p>{{bar}}</p>'
      element.replaceWith($compile(element.html(tpl).contents())(scope))
    }
  }
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/4YZ0CQZ4Ufck07IlOckB?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! I would love so, but the extra element is something I need to avoid. The extra element (even `span`) would break  the CSS. I'm trying to build [Bootstrap ToolBar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-toolbar)

Comment: @Jonathan I don't think so. I think I've replaced the ng-repeat with custom code but it's been a while